# jQuery Grab Content and Scroll page horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My goal is to grab content x and scroll page horizontally while mouse is moving until mouse stops (mouseup event), similar to a tablet swipe action.

Seems easy enough.. 
Get clientX on mousedown, 
scrollLeft by ClientX while moving,
Turn off mousemove function when done.

I've been playing with it for awhile and can't get the scroll effect I'm looking for..

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$('#thediv').on('mousedown', function(event) {  
    var e = event;   

    $('#thediv').on('mousemove',function(event){ 
        new_e = event; 
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: new_e.clientX  
        }, 300);   
        return false;  
     }); 

    $('#thediv').on('mouseup', function() { 
        $('#thediv').off('mousemove');  
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mD7mu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#greendiv').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $('#greendiv').on('mousemove', function(evt) {
        $('html,body').stop(false, true).animate({
            scrollLeft: e.pageX - evt.clientX
        });
    });
});
```

really close. simply subtracting the clientX from the pageX , and using `false,true` in the stop function will give you the desired effect, I think.

[here's the fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/mD7mu/1/)

Comment: Beautiful! Yes, this is the desired effect.

Comment: Intermittently, it's not stopping the mousemove function.. could this be a javascript error not catching the mouseup event to stop the mousemove function?

Comment: I found the problem with the mouseup issue, if the mouseup event fired outside of the div it would not turn off the mousemove event. I added function to remove mousemove event on mouseout as well - thanks for your help :)